# install ALUT on OSX

Tags: macos, haskell, glut, ghc

i am interested in installing the cabal package 
turing-music but i can't find the ALUT library on macports needed for the haskell binding to ALUT (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ALUT).

Where can i find ALUT development libraries on OSX 10.6.3 so that compile the cabal package ALUT.

Answer (score 3):

ALUT is not part of the OpenAL standard, so it is not included with OpenAL. Download the [freealut source code](https://github.com/vancegroup/freealut) and build it from source. If you want, create a Portfile and submit it to the Macports project.